# How to lock out other web pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an exam application where for the user to create an exam they have to go through these pages:

- create_session.php
- QandATable.php
- indivdiualmarks.php
- penalty.php
- complete.php

Now what I am worried about is the user can complete some of these pages but then either abandonded creating the exam by leaving out the other pages or they start creating an exam going trough some of the pages above but then be able to either go back on a previous page or pevious pages or skip pages by entering url of other pages which are coming up ahead.

So my question is that is there a way where I can stop the user skipping ahed pages or going back to previous pages? In other words they have to follow the exact steps of going through the five pages above in the exact order to create the exam.

For example if the user is on the the `QandATable.php page`, they cannot go back to the create_session.php page or they cannot skip ahead to the other pages until the `QandATable.php` has been successfully submitted? In other words lock out the other pages except the current page. Once the user has accessed the `complete.php` page then exam is completed and the `create_session.php` can be removed from the lockout as that is the first page.

If the user abandons a page such as the individualmarks.php, and the user goes back straight to the indivdualmarks.php page, then that is fine, but if they try to access another page, I am thinking of sending a prompt box or something similar stating:

> You already have an exam currently in creation, to continue with
>   creating the current exam click on this link (link to current page
>   user is on)
>
> If you want to create a new exam then please click on this link (link
>   to the create_session.php page).

I know what I am asking is not very simple but I don't want the user to mess up creating the exam unless they follow each step (each page) in the correct order so it doesn't mess with any data. Does anyone have a simple sample on how this could be achieved?

I am working with IE, Chrome. Safari, Firefox and Opera

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stepsStyle.css">
        <title>Follow Steps</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

//if user selects "Create New Assessment" Link, then use jquery/ajax below
//code below will access removesession.php where it will remove exam details which will be overwritten

$(function() {
    var link = $("#createLink");

    link.click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "removesession.php",
           async: false,
           type: "POST",
           success: function() {
                window.location.href = link.attr("href");
           }
         });

         //cancels the links true action of navigation
         return false;
    });
);

</script>

        </head>
        <body>

<?php

$steps = array('create_session.php', 'QandATable.php', 'individualmarks.php', 'penalty.php', 'complete.php');

$latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
// Track $latestStep in either a session variable or the DB and retrieve accordingly
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx > 1 ) {
    ?>

//set up a div box to display message on wether use should contine or not
<div class="boxed">
  You already have an exam currently in creation, to continue with creating the current exam click on this link: <br/><a href="">Continue with Current Assessment</a>
<br/>
If you want to create a new exam then please click on this link: <br/><a href="create_session.php" id="createLink">Create New Assessment</a>
</div>

<?

} else {
    // let the user do the step
}

?>
```

Got couple of questions regarding code above:

1. What should `$currentStep` variable equal to?
2. How do I link to its current page if user wants to continue with current exam?
3. Should I leave the else statement empty to let the user do the step?

Comment: log and track the users. a DB and sessions, doesn't sound difficult. im sure your already have a user management system for it

Comment: This because much easier if you break it down into smaller tasks - track what's been done, verify if they're following the workflow, display the message, etc.

Comment: just don't show the links until they complete the part you want. if they use their browser buttons then that is their own fault.

Comment: @Dagon At the moment I am using database to insert data after every page is inserted, thats why I don't want the user to skip pages or go back to pages they have already accessed and written data for. The problem I am having is coding it, if I can see a sample on how to do it then I can manipulate the code into being able to do this into my application

Comment: @ernie I will need help coding the workflow, got a sample I can see to start me off?

Comment: @nathanhayfield yeah but they could access the link of other pages by typing them on the browser's url, thats what Im worry about. Im worried about browser buttons as well but if it can recognise which page the user should be on, then hopefully it can lock out the other pages except for the page they should be on

Comment: I'd track the last completed state in a variable, and the workflow in a list.  On each page, check if the last completed state is greater than or equal to whatever the previous required steps are.  Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I'll try and write some code.

Comment: @ernie Ok give an answer on what you commented with the variable dealing with 2 pages (if you don't mind) and then I will manipulate it to more pages and take it further hopefully

Comment: you could use multiple jquery tabs with an ajax form on each. then they could easily navigate all the tabs and on tab switch you could autosave the current form. just use ajax to load and to save the forms.

Comment: @nathanhayfield AJAX concerns UX. It's not a way to solve his problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd track the last completed state in a variable, and the workflow in a list. On each page, check if the last completed state is greater than or equal to whatever the previous required steps are.  This is assuming that your workflow is completely linear.  Something like this:

```
$steps = array('create', 'table', 'marks', 'penalty', 'complete');

// Track $latestStep in either a session variable or the DB and retrieve accordingly
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx > 1 ) {
    // show error message
} else {
    // let the user do the step
}
```

**Edit:** Answering questions:

**What should $currentStep variable equal to?**

This should equal the page you're on and match a value in $steps; looks like it should be the filename of the current page.

**How do I link to its current page if user wants to continue with current exam?**

It sounds as if you're asking how to redirect to the correct step if the user is on the page.  The next step should be `$steps[$latestIdx + 1]`, e.g. the step after the latest step.

**Should I leave the else statement empty to let the user do the step?**

The else statement should contain all the code you want the user to execute.  Alternatively, if you're externalizing this, you should probably use return values, and return 1 if they can do the step, 0 if they can not.  Then on each page, you'd call this function, and depending on the return value, either show the page, or show the error.

Comment: Cool I have upvoted answer, I will have a go with this, obviously I am open to other solutions but if I can get this working then I will give you best answer. Just to make sure you said include this code in all 5 pages?

Comment: @user1941871 Yes, you would have this code on all the pages - I'd probably externalize it and then use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: Yeah good idea, I will externalize it, I will keep you up to date on what is happening

Comment: I have included an update below the question, just got some small questions I am little bit stuck with, other than that its getting there

Comment: @user1941871 - those are actually big questions, fundamental to understanding what the code is intended to do.  Take some time and try and understand the code before just cutting and pasting.  I've added some comments in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will still keep giving it a go, My second question you did not understand `How do I link to its current page if user wants to continue with current exam?`, What I meant is that if the user clicks on the link in the div box `Continur with Current Assessment`, how do I use the `</a>` to link to the current page the user should be on? Can I use `$currentStep` to link the page the user should be on?

Comment: Thanks for update I realised I messed up in question 2, I should of said `How do I link to correct page if user wants to continue with current exam`, I think I sorted out first question by doing the following `$currentstep = basename(__FILE__);` so I just need to sort out the other 2 questions. I will keep you up to date anyway and I marked your answer. I think your answer will really help people who want to perform a similar functionality :)

Answer (score 3):

Security through obscurity is indeed a naive scheme: you should always assume that your URLs are public. Here you require a *wizard-like* interface, which in turn is a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Assuming your system already has *users*, you need to find a workflow engine (or a FSM implementation, or develop a simple one yourself) and track the user submissions inside every flow.

At the beginning of each and every page you must validate the user's *position*, ie you must say if the user in the current *state* can access the requested resource. If he can't just redirect him, otherwise show the requested page.

BTW, it seems you are building your application from scratch. The fast track is using a framework, for example [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). I'm suggesting Cake because I just found [this nice plugin](https://github.com/burriko/cakephp-state-machine-behavior) (never used it myself, but the API is really nice and Cake itself is great for learning purposes)

Comment: The problem is coding it which be my problem, at the moment I am tracking the user with a session with these variables: `if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];
      
  }
  
if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {
 
      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];
      
  }` This is stored in a php script known as `member.php`

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how storing the username in the session relates to state management. Also, I strongly suggest not building your app on your own: you'll end up with an insecure, slow and difficult to maintain load of code. Finding support will be difficult because nobody knows your libraries. And you won't learn best practices and state-of-the-art tools, which are really important things in tech jobs

Comment: Yeah the whole application is made from scratch, I am only creating the functionality of the application, somebody else will be doing the front end and decide how to make it look nice